# Given a target, find the sum of the target from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

Given a list of numbers and a target value, I am to find the sum of two numbers that matches the target and returns the indexes of the sum from the array.

I have tried:

```
nums = [2,5,5,11]
target = 10


def nums_sum_target(nums, target):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for j in range(len(nums)):
            if j == len(nums) - 1:
                target_sum = nums[i]
            else:
                print(j+1, "inner loop 2")
                target_sum = nums[i] + nums[j+1]
                
            if target_sum == target:
                print([nums[i], nums[j+1]])
                return [i, j+1]
```

I expected: [1,2]

I had: [1,1]

Comment: This feels like an off-by-one error. A way to check that is trying it with other nums and target values. Check where you're using `nums[j+1]`.

Comment: Okay, I have tried it with different nums and target values and it all worked out well except with the list in the question (thus, [2,5,5,11])

Comment: (1) All you need in the inner loop is `if nums[i] + nums[j] == target: return i, j`. (2) The inner loop should be `for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)): ...`.

Comment: Try modifying `for j in range(len(nums))` to `for j in range(i + 1, len(nums))`

Comment: As they say, "pay it forward"  Posting your solution as an answer + explaining what worked and why is a great way to help the next person and to learn!

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are sorted, you can take advantage of that and just iterate from both ends like so:

```
def find_sum(numbers, target):
    assert numbers  # Should have at least 1 number
    left = 0
    right = len(numbers) - 1
    while left < right:
        total = numbers[left] + numbers[right]
        if total == target:
            return (left, right)
        elif total < target:
            left += 1
        else:
            right -= 1
    raise LookupError(f"Sum {target} not found")
```

Testing the function:

```
numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5]
target = 6

indices = find_sum(numbers, target)
print(indices)  # prints (0, 2)
```

No need for a dictionary or anything else, just the list and the target, and this is an extremely efficient way, with a worse case of `O(n)`.